# Помогите пожалуйста с этим кодом

Tags: java

Напишите код, который генерирует случайную строчную букву.

можно ли сделать это в одном System.out.print(); ?

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println((char)(1072 + new Random().nextInt(31)));
```

Мне нечего делать=))

Comment: Только имхо: читабельнее вместо чисел использовать тип char в таком виде (char) (new Random().nextInt('z' - 'a') + 'a')

Comment: @АлександрПоташев, 1072 - это кириллическая `а`, а не латинская.

Comment: @dimagor555, а с какого перепуга 31? Насколько я помню, верхняя граница не включительно, тогда должно быть 33. Если включительно, то 32. Ну и ещё `ё` в этот диапазон не попадает.

Answer (score 3):

Можно:

```
System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{(byte) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(97, 122 + 1)}));
System.out.println((char) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(97, 122 + 1));
```